# How to make a list consisted by other lists?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a list contains several smaller lists, and double the first element of each sub-lists.Here is my code:

```
 double_the_first::(Num a)=>[[a]]->[a]
 double_the_first list = case list of 
 []                   ->[]
 [[x]]                ->[x*2]
 [x:xs]               ->map(*2)(map(head)[x:xs])
```

How can I represent a list like [[2,3],[4,5]]? I know my code is wrong, but haskell does not show any error, how? It will not work when I input a list like this:

```
 double_the_first [[2,3],[2,4],[4,3]]
*** Exception: test.hs:(3,25)-(6,51): Non-exhaustive patterns in case
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Enable warnings with the `-Wall` flag: it will help you notice many common mistakes, including not considering all possible cases as in the snippet above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First write a function that does what you want to each element of the list. In your case, each element is itself a list.

```
doubleFirst :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
doubleFirst [] = []
doubleFirst (x:xs) = (2*x:xs)
```

Then use `map` to apply that function to the list of elements:

```
map doubleFirst [[2,3],[2,4],[4,3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some cases when the list is empty. You can change your code following way. I have added possibility that list is empty. I think you wanted to use different type of result.

```
double_the_first::(Num a)=>[[a]]->[[a]]
double_the_first list = case list of 
    []                   -> []
    (([]):xs)            -> [[]] ++ double_the_first xs
    ((y:ys):xs)          -> [(2*y:ys)] ++ double_the_first xs
```

Comment: Thanks, and my function is work now. However can you explain about your second case? I tried to delete it and the code still work properly.

Comment: @Jerry Try `double_the_first [[],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`